# Electron: Share constants file between both main/renderer process with tyescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

Electron w/ Typescript: Share a constants.ts file between both the main and renderer process.

Folder Structure:

src/

- main

  - main.ts
- renderer

  - renderer.ts
- shared

  - constants.ts

```
//constants.ts

export const constants= {
  foo: '123'
  bar: 'xyz'
}

//main.ts
import { constants} from '../shared/constants'

app.on("ready", async function () {
  console.log(constants)

});


//renderer.ts
import { constants} from '../shared/constants'

console.log(constants)
```

IntelliSense correctly reads/sees the constants. and main.ts correctly console logs constants. However, renderer.ts throws an error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../shared/constants'`
The output js do have exact same structure as source code, (dist/src/(main/shared/renderer)

I'm using the electron typescript quickstart template: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript

This is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist/src",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

One thing to note is am using an older version of electron.

```
// versions
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "electron": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
```

I found this project that does exactly what I want to do with sharing a constants file between both processes, but failing to replicate it
https://github.com/ci010/electron-vue-next

I strictly just want to share constants, not mutable variables/objects.

Any idea to know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple although not elegant solution (because on renderer side all constants are shoved in the global namespace). See below an example (all files in the same folder):

const_shared.js

```js
const APP_NAME = "Rocket Launcher";

// exports only if const_shared.js
// is required by 'main' process
if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    exports.APP_NAME = APP_NAME
}
```

index.html

```html
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="const_shared.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="renderer.js"></script>
```

renderer.js

```js
// constant APP_NAME is in global
// namespace of 'renderer' process 
// because of 
// <script> with src=const_shared.js
console log(APP_NAME);
```

main.js

```js
// 'main' process
const { APP_NAME } 
= require("const_shared.js");

console.log(APP_NAME);
```